# How to make PHP action in AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database

I created a PHP page that Insert into the database the value in the textbox, when someone click on the button it's redirect to the php page, But I want it to make the PHP action without redirecting, So how can I do it in ajax?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: To do it with ajax you have to... use ajax. You're not so far. PHP has a little in common with ajax. It's javascript issue. Use for example jQuery as woz has adviced

Answer (score 0):

woz and dragoste are right. Use jQuery to make it happen. you can use this function, it will fit to your requirement.

Here i used jQuery validation library http://jqueryvalidation.org/ to validate the form .

```
  $(function()
  {
    var form = $("#booking_form").validate();

        $('#success').hide();
        $('#failure').hide();

        $("form#your_form").submit(function() {
                    if(form.valid())
                    {
                        var name = $("#txtName").val();
                        var email = $("#txtEmail").val();
                        var phone = $("#txtPhone").val();

                        $.ajax({
                        url: "process_form.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                                'name': name,
                                'email': email,
                                'phone': phone
                                },
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data) {
                              if(data.status == 'success')
                              {
                                    $('#your_form').hide();               
                                    $('#success').show();
                              }
                              else if(data.status == 'error')
                              {
                                    $('#failure').show();
                              }
                            }
                        });
                return false;
                }
        }); 
});
```